# Pulling data from and writing back to an Excel spreadsheet in PowerShell

Tags: powershell, scripting

Right, I'm putting a script together to be run post-Windows install to change a few settings, re-name the computer and join a domain. I've got everything working fine but where it currently asks the user to provide a computername (which they will be taking from a spreadsheet) I'd ideally like the script to take the next available name from the file and then write back a value for the adjacent field with a value provided by the user (the end-user's name).

Is this at all possible or am I expecting too much here?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Yes, it's possible. [Check this module](https://github.com/dfinke/ImportExcel)

Answer (score 0):

Check out the PowerShell Module https://www.powershellgallery.com/packages/ImportExcel/5.1.1